# How to execute testcases through Python Class using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, python-class

So I'm trying to build a bot with python and selenium
this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get('https://www.Instagram.com/')
```

The problem is nothing will happen when I try the python bot.py
I've tried py bot.py too
it didin't throw any errors but the commands really do nothing

please can someone help me findout what the problem is???

I've tried `driver = webdriver.chrome` ... outside the class and it works but when i put it in the InstagramBot class it wont work

im using python3.6.5
and ive tried other python versions too
it didint help

Comment: Is this the entire code? Have you remembered to initialise your class to call the function? e.g. `i = InstagramBot()`. Might be better to add another method to run your bot `def run(self): ...` then you can call `InstagramBot().run()`

Comment: yes sir its not complete but it will be when i find out whats the problrm

Answer (score 1):

You were close enough. As you have defined the *Class*, now you simply need to create an instance so the constructor gets executed calling it from the *main* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
    self.driver.get('https://www.Instagram.com/')

InstagramBot("naa-G", "naa-G")
```